# Start Node.JS program onload mac OS

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, service

I know that we can add node.js program(script) to windows services, that will starts onload. Is any similar approach exists to start node.js program on mac os onload? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-launch should do the trick:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch

Or for a more comprehensive and customizeable solution, node-mac module:
https://github.com/coreybutler/node-mac

If you want to do it manually, check this out:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Hope it helps!